# need help with jQuery when not hovering over a particular element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a navigation div (the id is navigation) i am thinking of writing a code that executes when i am not hovering over the navigation. Can somebody explain me how can that be possible with jQuery.

```
<ul id='navigation'>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

```
#navigation li{
 display:inline;
 float:left;   
    width:50px;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    padding:2px;
}
```

```
jQuery("#navigation").mouseout(function(){

   alert("hi"); 

});
```

Now with this code even when i am moving from one li to another mouseout function is called. However i am expecting it to be called everytime out of this navigation.

Comment: Can you explain a little more.  Do you mean you want the code to execute after you leave the navigation, or something that runs literally all the time when you aren't hovering the navigation.

Comment: Yes something that runs everytime i am not hovering over the navigation.

Comment: sorry guys i am adding the code know i believe that would explain my problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do something when a user's mouse leaves and element, use the [mouseout event](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/):

```
$('#navigation').mouseout(function() {
  alert("You left me! :'(");
});
```

If you also want to do this when the page first loads you'll need to add it as a [ready event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  Create a boolean flag that equals true.

Step 2:  Add a mouseover function to the naviagtion.  That function should make the boolean flag equal false

Step 3:  Add a mouseout function to the naviagtion.  That function should make the boolean flag equal to false

Step 4:  At the end of the page ready event add a while (true) { } loop, in that loop check the boolean with an if statement.  Put whatever code you need in the if statement.  Make sure you also have a delay at the end of the while loop.